# Windows popup "Is this a device you develop on?"

Tags: windows-10, security, notifications

I just got a weird desktop notification, asking me if this is a device I develop on. When I clicked it, it brought me to a broken page in Settings and asked if I wanted to open Feedback Hub. When I clicked that, Feedback Hub just showed an error: (something like) Feedback Hub has no information or something went wrong.

I did install a Windows update 2 days ago. 
I have not made any other hardware or software changes to my machine is several months.

Are there any Windows programs that actually need to know if I use my device for development? 
Or should I be doing a format/re-install procedure at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please See This: "Feedback Hub" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_Hub

When you updated Windows did it persuade you to log in using a 
Microsoft Account?  Or are you logged in locally?
  Pin or Password?
Because it sounds like you are logged into Microsoft.

Change Microsoft Account to Local Account?

Open Settings > Accounts > Your Info....

> Sign in with a local account instead.

MS got me to update to a new Windows 10 when installing and 
after entering a PIN, signed me into the MS Account online.

About 1 week later I could not Logon either way.

I reinstalled and logged onto the LOCAL every time after. 
Hope this helps ;)

dval I edited your post in error, sorry about that everyone.
I meant to edit this box.  I am glad it helped. Thanks for the feedback.
Yes, Feedhub is a legigimate application from Microsoft.

Comment: So, is it implied that it was a legitimate question from Feedback Hub because that is what popped up? Probably just time to review notification and privacy settings in that case. FH has, until tonight, been entirely passive unless there was an error with the option to report. The link is useful, it's more than the support page offers.